# How to run corda kotlin example correctly

Tags: corda

**Problem:**

I am trying Corda official documentation hello word application. After Deploying CorDapp I issued

```
start IOUFlow iouValue: 99, otherParty: "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
```

This command on Party A. After doing that I tried to check the ledger state by issuing this command on Party A and B.

```
run vaultQuery contractStateType: com.template.states.IOUState
```

But it gives the same output as the notary like this.

```
states: []
statesMetadata: []
totalStatesAvailable: -1
stateTypes: "UNCONSUMED"
otherResults: []
```

But Output should be like this.

```
states:
- state:
    data:
      value: 99
      lender: "C=GB,L=London,O=PartyA"
      borrower: "C=US,L=New York,O=PartyB"
      participants:
      - "C=GB,L=London,O=PartyA"
      - "C=US,L=New York,O=PartyB"
    contract: "com.template.contract.IOUContract"
    notary: "C=GB,L=London,O=Notary"
    encumbrance: null
    constraint:
      attachmentId: "F578320232CAB87BB1E919F3E5DB9D81B7346F9D7EA6D9155DC0F7BA8E472552"
  ref:
    txhash: "5CED068E790A347B0DD1C6BB5B2B463406807F95E080037208627565E6A2103B"
    index: 0
statesMetadata:
- ref:
    txhash: "5CED068E790A347B0DD1C6BB5B2B463406807F95E080037208627565E6A2103B"
    index: 0
  contractStateClassName: "com.template.state.IOUState"
  recordedTime: 1506415268.875000000
  consumedTime: null
  status: "UNCONSUMED"
  notary: "C=GB,L=London,O=Notary"
  lockId: null
  lockUpdateTime: 1506415269.548000000
totalStatesAvailable: -1
stateTypes: "UNCONSUMED"
otherResults: []
```

This is my build.gradle task deployNodes.

```
task deployNodes(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {
    nodeDefaults {
        projectCordapp {
            deploy = true
        }
        cordapp project(':contracts')
        cordapp project(':workflows')
    }
    directory "./build/nodes"
    node {
        name "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
        notary = [validating : true]
        p2pPort 10002
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10003")
            adminAddress("localhost:10043")
        }
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyA,L=London,C=GB"
        p2pPort 10005
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10006")
            adminAddress("localhost:10046")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }
    node {
        name "O=PartyB,L=New York,C=US"
        p2pPort 10008
        rpcSettings {
            address("localhost:10009")
            adminAddress("localhost:10049")
        }
        rpcUsers = [[ user: "user1", "password": "test", "permissions": ["ALL"]]]
    }

}
```

I tried a lot to find out a solution to this problem on the internet but I was unable to do so as I am a newcomer to Corda. Can someone help me to solve this issue? Thank you very much.

Comment: When you ran the flow, did it complete successfully? Did you see the returned transaction hash on the screen? Also did you have all the 3 nodes (PartyA, PartyB, and Notary) up?

Comment: @AdelRustum nothing was there on the screen after starting the flow. Yeah, all three server terminals are running.

Comment: If you didn't get anything on the screen, then the flow didn't complete. Check the logs of your nodes (inside `build/nodes/PartyA/logs`). You can also start the node in debug mode (https://docs.corda.net/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging) and put breakpoints on your code to see where it's failing.

Comment: @AdelRustum Thank you very much. I got error on logs after checking it. After solving that issue my problem solved.

Comment: Ok, I'll add my remark as an answer; please accept it to mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you didn't get anything on the screen, then the flow didn't complete.
Check the logs of your nodes (inside `build/nodes/PartyA/logs`).
You can also start the node in debug mode (https://docs.corda.net/node-commandline.html#enabling-remote-debugging) and put breakpoints on your code to see where it's failing.